# Error recording time with CudaEvent

Tags: cuda

I am using cudaEvent methods to find the time my kernel takes to execute.Here is the code as given in the manual.

```
  cudaEvent_t start,stop;
  float time=0;
  cudaEventCreate(&start);
  cudaEventCreate(&stop);      
  cudaEventRecord(start,0);
  subsampler<<<gridSize,blockSize>>>(img_redd,img_greend,img_blued,img_height,img_width,final_device_r,final_device_g,final_device_b);
  cudaEventRecord(stop,0);
  cudaEventSynchronize(stop);
  cudaEventElapsedTime(&time,start,stop);
```

Now when I run this and try to see the time it comes something like 52428800.0000(values differ but are of this order) .I know it is in milliseconds but still this is a huge number especially when this program execution doesnt take more than a minute.Can someone point out why this is happening .I really need to find how much time the kernel takes to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the return values of each of those CUDA calls. At the very least call cudaGetLastError() at the end to check everything was successful.

If you get an error during the kernel execution then try running your app with cuda-memcheck, especially if you have an Unspecified Launch Failure, to check for illegal memory accesses.

Comment: Thanks for the rep.I call the cudaGetLastError() function right before finishing the program and it says "no error".moreover I am writing a image and that turns out correctly so I am pretty sure code is ok.I am just amazed though why such a large number would show up for a program that takes less than a minute to execute.

Comment: What platform are you on (OS and bitness, CUDA version)? Check that you're compiling both host and device for the same bitness, i.e. if you're compiling for a 64-bit host then make sure you have `-m64` on the nvcc command line.